# Face detection demo using Siamese Network

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, face-detection

I have learned the overview and functionality of **Siamese network** as it is **One Shot Learning**, I have tried some link from web which can give the demo of face detection using Siamese.

But I am not able to find any demo in which all the steps like training dataset, verification and testing steps are there. Can anyone have any reference link in which I can just detect the face from camera and comapre it with my Training dataset and that functionality I want using Siamese whether it is using  tensorflow or keras.

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do take some time to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic here.

Comment: Riya, If my answer solves your problem, please accept it and do upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [example](https://www.kaggle.com/arpandhatt/siamese-neural-networks) what you are looking for. The author has explained very nicely with python script, to find the similarity between ships and ice-berg, which can be easily expandable to any other application.